# How to send message to grandparent View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I understand [how to send data to a **child** View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/3681880) when calling it with a segue. I think I also understand [how to send data to a **parent** View Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LHDsSWc680) through the use of protocols and delegates. But how do I send data to a **grandparent** View Controller?

Options that I've considered:

- Send the data to the parent and have the parent send it to the grandparent. But this seems like a lot of extra work when then parent doesn't need to know.
- Use `NSNotificationCenter`. But (1) it is only the grandparent that needs to know, not the whole world, and (2) from the scant Swift documentation that I've found, `NSNotificationCenter` seems very unSwiftlike.

Comment: One way is that if you have NavigationController stack then you can using that you can access grandparent and send the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `protocols` in this case too. I have done this way :

In the `current` controller(lets say `grandchild` controller), just intialize your `grandparent` controller and set `delegate`(same as you do in `prepareForSegues` in case of `parent` controller)

```
//use this lines when you want call the grandparent controller
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let grandParentVC= storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("grandPVC") as! UIViewController
grandParentVC.delegate = self
//now call your delegate method here
```

As you specified, you know `protocols` (the links you included). Let me know if anything is unclear to you.

Hope this will work for you too!

Comment: I wouldn't say that I know protocols very well, just a bit of theoretical knowledge. I went a different direction in my app, but until I hear differently I will mark this answer as solving the problem that I presented.

Comment: I meant : you know atleast basics of protocols(the links you mentioned) so that you may easily go with my answer :)

Comment: @iRiziya shouldn't the `grandChildVC` be the one which has the `delegate` property?